# Find Linux Total Bandwidth in One Line

Tags: linux, command-line, bandwidth

Is there a command to find the total bandwidth used by a Linux box since startup, that returns one line?

The reason I'm asking is I'd like to call this shell not using a terminal and output the results through the web, rather than having a nice animating terminal.

Comment: would something like http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/ work instead? Its not a cli application, but you could use to do what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
netstat -N -i | awk '{if ($1 > 0 && $4 > 0) print $1,$4,$8}' | grep -i -v name | uniq
```

The output is like this:

> Iface RX-OK TX-OK eth0 16257756 24735708 lo 15049 15049

(Up and Down in Bytes, by interface)

EDIT: After playing for a while:

```
netstat -i | awk '{print ($4+$8)}'
```

Is shows only the sum(in bytes) of every interface:

> [claudiop@Workstation]# netstat -i | awk '{print ($4+$8)}'
>
> 0 0 40994492 30102

(I don't know from where came the "0"s, but you can easly filter the output)

[Source](http://forums.hostgator.com/can-cehck-vps-bandwidth-usage-linux-t154560.html?s=56d1403fc39f71b577121ebb57e39a11&)

Answer (score 2):

`vnstat | awk '$7~/total/ {print $8,$9}'` will output something like this:

> 8.03 MiB

Comment: It gives no output here.

Comment: Did you install vnstat? Also, for the first few minutes after installation it won't display any data.

Comment: If i didn't it had an output like this: "bash: vnstat: command not found", but it simply gives no output. I have vnstat, and i am using arch.